# Redirect URL to another URL by regex with Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I want to redirect one URL to another URL through traefik.

I am using docker for this configuration and below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: containous/whoami
    container_name: "whoami_cont"
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - 80:80
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - 8080:8080
    labels:
      - traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
      - traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=http://localhost:8081/4
```

then I am running docker-compose command successfully. Then I am going to hit any URL which matching regex pattern but URL is not redirecting to another URL - http://localhost:8081/4 as per configuration.
I am using traefik version 2.0

Please let me know if any configuration is missing.

Comment: `containous/whoami` is not really Traefik docker image, it's just a simple server used for testing.

Comment: Then which image should I use? I have tried traefik:v2.1.0 image but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [official example](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/), it seems that your configuration is missing an actual Traefik instance:

```
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

After adding Traefik to your docker-compose file and defining [middleware](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/overview/), you should attach your middleware to a router:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=test-replacepathregex"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=^/foo/(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=/bar/$$1"
```

The full and working (but simplified) example of replacing `/foo/123` by `/bar/123`:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=test-replacepathregex"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=^/foo/(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=/bar/$$1"
```

Comment: Thanks Yury for this. It builds successfully but when I hit the URL, it is not redirecting to replacement URL. I can see the output of the whoami service as shown in official example but URL redirection is not happening.

Comment: Because it is not redirect, it's a replacement: you see the same value in browser, but the backend sees another value (look at `whoami` reponse). If you need to redirect, use redirect middleware which is similar to replacepath middleware.

Comment: Thanks Yury. whoami service is responding perfect for replacement but when I am using redirection middleware, browser URL is not redirecting and 404 page not found displays.
Any idea for this?

Comment: Most likely you misconfigured the middleware and need to look into it. Anyway, the original issue in the question is that you didn't actually attach the middleware to a router. Now when you do attach it, you can start debugging the next issue.

Comment: Yes Yury, you are correct about attach the middleware to a router. I am missing this part. Now I am able to redirect it successfully with your provided example. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Hello. What if I wanted to replace not just the path but the entire URL? Say if this replace regex is detected, /v1/auth/verify, I wanted to forward this to another service, http://auth.docker.localhost ?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward if you are using an `Ingressroute`. Let say I want to redirect from `example.com` to `app.example.com` using traefik

First thing would be to create a Middleware :

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: example-redirectregex
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: ^https://example.com/(.*)
    replacement: https://app.example.com/${1}
```

If you already have an `Ingressroute` then you can add an additional rule that will point `example.com` to the same backend service used by `app.example.com` and use the middleware we created above

```
- kind: Rule
    match: Host(`example.com`)
    middlewares:
    - name: example-redirectregex
      namespace: traefik
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: master-prod
      namespace: app-web
      port: 80
```

So, finally your `Ingressroute` should look something like the below:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app: app-web
    product: example.com
  name: example-com
  namespace: traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`example.com`)
    middlewares:
    - name: example-redirectregex
      namespace: traefik
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: example
      namespace: app-web
      port: 80
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`app.example.com`)
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: example
      namespace: app-web
      port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: cert-example-com
```

Now, if you browse `example.com` it should redirect you to `app.example.com`

Comment: How anyone in the world would like to write these 50 lines to do something 1 line should do is beyond me. Or that it is somehow straightforward. Quite amazing, but mostly a sad reflection of the world. :'(